# Powershell - export csv value into specific column

Tags: powershell

Having some issues with the syntax. I'm trying to copy the variable value into another csv column.

```
$file1 = import-csv C:\temp\csv1.csv
$file2 = import-csv C:\Temp\csv2.csv
$file3 = import-csv C:\Temp\csv3.csv

foreach ($line in $file1) {
foreach ($row in $file2) {
    if ($line.col1 -eq $row.col1){
        #this is the part im having issues with:
         $row.col2 = $line.col3 | Export-Csv #???
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `$row` is a reference to an object in `$file2`. When you update `$row`, `$file2` is automatically updated. Therefore, you can just wait until you have made all your updates. Then export to CSV at the end --> `$file2 | Export-Csv ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is a reference to an object in `$file2`. When you update `$row`, `$file2` is automatically updated. Therefore, you can just wait until you have made all your updates before exporting to CSV. So assuming your logic is correct for when you want to update `col2` of `$file2`, you can do the following:

```
$file1 = import-csv C:\temp\csv1.csv
$file2 = import-csv C:\Temp\csv2.csv

foreach ($line in $file1) {
    foreach ($row in $file2) {
        if ($line.col1 -eq $row.col1) {
            $row.col2 = $line.col3
        }
    }
}
$file2 | Export-Csv -Path NewFile.Csv -NoType
```